# Android eclipse development TextView Assistance

Tags: android, eclipse, textview

Whats up? I've been trying to learn a few basics when it comes to coding, and I've got a question regarding the `helloworld`-app.

A basic `Hello world!`-app shouldn't be hard to accomplish, as it shows the text "Hello world or whatever..u want it to be". Anyway, how would I go about making it display two, or even three separate lines?

For example:

```
Hello, world
[Second line]
[Third line]
```

I just can't figure out how to do this, so if anyone could point me in the right direction, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: TextView automatically handles text wrapping. As text outgrows the textview width it will be pushed to the next line.

Answer (score 4):

Isn't `\n` the way to go on that one?

An other way would be to wrap the `TextView`s in an `LinearLayout`, and fill them each with one sentence.

`Edit (response to OP):`

You can do it programmatically by using the following code (in your `onCreate()`-

```
//Grab the TextView that's been deflated from the XML-file
TextView theTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.{The id of your TextView});

//Set the text to a three-rowed message
theTextView.setText("Hello world!\nMy name is ninetwozero.\nLorem ipsum wouldn't fit here");
```

Remember to change `{The id of your TextView}` into the actual id of your `TextView` that's been set in the `xml`-layout file.

Comment: well as i said before im new too this, would you care to explain in detail? if you will..?

Answer (score 3):

Is this you want??

```
 <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView android:text="First Line" android:id="@+id/textView2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
    <TextView android:text="Second Line" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
    <TextView android:text="Third Line" android:id="@+id/textView3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

'\n' is a special char that means 'new line'
so it is "hello world\nLine 2\nLine 3"

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView yourText = (TextView)findViewById(TheId);
yourText.setText("Hello \n World \n Welcome to my app ?");
```

It display something like this :
1st line : Hello.
2nd line : World.
3rd line : Welcom to my app ?

Is it what you wanted ?

Comment: Thank you Tsunaze it works like a charm i use this    tv.setText("Hello, Users \n snd line");